# DAPP login with all wallets

Tags: blockchain, wallets, dapps

how i can make this type of login modal that support all the wallets for my dapp ?
[image]

Comment: I think this repo eplains exactly that https://github.com/DappPocket/Ethereum-Wallet-SDK (Im not the owner of that repo, I just found it one day)

Answer (score 0):

I  used this package https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal
they have all the documentation and example project, check them out.

Comment: Thanks man but i think this package does not support hardware wallets but i found that library that is being used in the screenshot 
https://docs.blocknative.com/onboard#

Comment: I thought web3modal were working on integrating hardware wallets, glad you found what you wanted.